# Nonlinear Two Stage Least Squares Instrumental Variable method

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, cointegration, instrumental-variables, 2sls

I am trying to figure out how [this paper](http://business.uow.edu.au/content/groups/public/@web/@commerce/@econ/documents/doc/uow067296.pdf) estimates extended Solow production function using nonlinear two stage least squares instrumental variable method (or non linear 2SLSIV).

The full specification and the definition of the model is given on pages 18-19. It is a time series model. Also, the model appears to be linear in parameters, and the equation has unmatching brackets.

Model on page 19 is given below
[image]

Could anyone please comment on the estimation method?